# Prevent application to go fullscreen

Tags: xfce, manjaro, fullscreen

I have an application (namely zoom) that automatically goes fullscreen and does not provides a way to disable that (you can exit fullscreen but you have to do that every time someone shares its screen). I wonder if there is a way to deny any application to go fullscreen or to make it think its fullscreen but fake it inside a window. I guess a VM would do the job but its a great cost for that.
I'm not looking for a zoom specific solution for now,hence this question.
I'm on manjaro with xfce.

Comment: You could try running it inside Xephyr and see what you get?

Answer (score 0):

The solution using Xephyr suggested in comments worked. Its not perfect (no clipboard sharing so entering zoom meeting id and password by hand is painful) but the fullscreen remains inside the xephyr window and that's exactly what I wanted and the kind of hacky solutions linux can be counted on.

Comment: You could try and see if firejail can improve this: it supports Xephyr as backend and has options related to clipboard. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/firejail#Firejail_with_Xorg